# active job in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-activerecord, rails-activejob

I am looking forward to active job for active record for rails 4. I search related to it. I found **gem 'delayed_job_active_record'** . But this supports Rails 3+.
In that I want to run the job everyday at some specific time to check the due date. If due date reached, before some particular period Want to send alert message/mail. And I am using devise for authentication.
And also I see the **gem 'devise-async-activejob'**. Is this affect my authentication system? Which gem can I use for  this scenario without affecting my existing features. Suggest any Guide or documentation or sample.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the queue_adapter in config/application.rb

config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
See the rails guide for more details.

See

- http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html
- https://blog.codeship.com/how-to-use-rails-active-job/